# Sort an array relatively to one of his internal data in jQuery/Js

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting

Is there a way to specify in a `sort()` method a parameters that should be taken as reference?

For example : 
I have an array of element `<li>...</li>` which has in parameter the data : `date = Wed Apr 20 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)` (for example).

Now let say I have multiple `<li>` with different date and I want those to be sort by chronological order. First I do an array with them. Then I try to sort them but **I don't get how or even if it is possible to specify a parameter**.

Something like

```
$date = $.makeArray($('#divRss li'))
$date.sort(function(a,b) { 
    return new Date(a.date).getTime() - new Date(b.date).getTime() 
});
```

Where date should be the `data('date')`.

Here is a Fiddle for test/example purpose : https://jsfiddle.net/Baldrani/sj8m8d96/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the HTML you provide there are no elements with a `date` attribute. The only date I can see is the value of the `.itemDate` elements within each `li`. You can amend your `sort()` to work with this value instead. Once the `sort()` has run, you can re-append the `li` to their parent element in their sorted order. Also note that you don't need to use `$.makeArray()` on the jQuery object and `#divRss` does not exist (although I assume this is just missing in your example HTML).

With all that said, try this:

```
$('.feedEkList li').sort(function(a, b) {
    var aDate = $(a).find('.itemDate').text();
    var bDate = $(b).find('.itemDate').text();
    return new Date(bDate).getTime() - new Date(aDate).getTime();
}).appendTo('.feedEkList');
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/sj8m8d96/7/)

Note this is ordered in descending date order. To change this to ascending, subtract `bDate` from `aDate`.

Comment: Hooow I get it !! Thank you I learned form you today ! Ps : When I meant date it was the output of this : `$('li').each(function() { console.log($(this).data('date')) })`

Comment: No problem, glad to help